# What is the definition of "dating" in this context?

Tags: vocabulary, learning

I was reading the stackoverflow for some answer that would help my case and came across this comment of a user:

> With current browsers (this question is dating a bit now), you can use the much simpler vw (viewport width) unit:

"this question is dating a bit now" <-- is dating here means becomening obsolete or out of date???

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is how I would interpret it.  It would be clearer to say "This question is becoming dated".

This expression is fairly non-idiomatic, but I suppose it is not carefully written.  It's just a parenthetical comment on an internet forum.

Comment: I believe by "dating (the ing suffix)" he meant it is STARTING to become obsolete by the time he answered that. Make any sense?

Comment: I don't think there is much analysis that can be done.  "It is becoming dated" would have the sense of "starting to become". I can see no particular reason to use the slightly odd phrasing of "it is dating", so I assume it is just careless writing.

Answer (score -1):

The intended meaning is probably

> to determine the period of time to which something belongs : to determine the date (see date entry 2 sense 3) of
> *date* an antique
> *dated* the fossils to the Triassic period

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/date

So yes, the writer probably meant it in the sense of "this question is very specific to a particular time period" or "this question is out of [out of date](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/out-of-date)."  It's a bit of a strange usage; it would be more common to say "this question is [**dated**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dated) now."

Comment: I'm really curious why this answer got downvoted.